# Sorting posts based on votes in a relational database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database

I have two database tables.
posts and votes.

```
**posts table;**
id | user_id |        content         
 1 |       1 | first post   
 2 |       1 | second post  
 3 |       1 | third                 

**votes table;**

 vote | post_id  
------+---------
 t    |       1
 t    |       2
 t    |       2
 t    |       2
 f    |       2
 t    |       3
 t    |       3
 t    |       3
vote is a boolean with values true or false
```

Now I want to find all the posts sorted in descending order such that the result reflects the votes (number of upvotes (true vote) - number of downvotes (false vote)).

```
SELECT  posts.*, count(votes.vote is true) -  count(votes.vote is false) as vote_count
FROM "posts"
LEFT JOIN votes AS votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY vote_count DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The above query returns the result but all the values in vote_count field are 0(zero). (I know I am a NOOB!)

What will be the correct query in this scenario?

The desired result is (values inside '()' is for reference purpose only):

```
 id | votes | content        
----+-----------------------
  3 | 3(3-0)| third 
  2 | 2(3-1)| second post
  1 | 1(1-0)| first post
```

Thanks.

P.S. - Will help a lot if you can give me corresponding rails query too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Inner join with CASE WHEN THEN as below:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 't' then 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Votes, post_id, content
FROM votes v INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id = v.post_id
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 't' then 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC
```

Comment: Worked!
Just correct the second line with 'ON v.post_id = p.id'.

Comment: Glad it worked and thanks for raising it. I have corrected the typo :)

Comment: And we can also replace 'SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 't' then 1 ELSE -1 END)' in 4th line with 'Votes', without causing any errors, right?

Comment: No you wont be able to use alias there.

Comment: SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 't' then 1 ELSE -1 END) AS votes, post_id FROM vote_posts v INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id = v.post_id GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 100; is working. 
Maybe because actual database is a little bit different. :)

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4